# JS version of Ruby's .each_with_index

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, indexing, iteration

What is a method (or combination of methods) in Javascript that will iterate over the elements of an array and, aside operating on the elements of the array, will also allow me to use the index number of the current element?

In ruby this would equate to something like this:

```
array.each_with_index{ |element,index| element.method(index) }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For arrays(`[1, 2, 3]`) you can use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
array.forEach(function (element, index) {

});
```

for `Objects` (`{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`) you can use `.forEach` with combination `Object.keys`

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
   var value = obj[key];
});
```